# Is there a way to assign a customer a customer ID in SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to assign customers IDs so that I can see all of their loans for example

| Loan Number | Borrower | Amount $ | Customer ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Eagle | 100 |  |
| 2 | Eagle | 299 |  |
| 3 | Pidge | 333 |  |
| 4 | Hawk | 123 |  |

I would want to assign all of the borrowers a customer ID and then have a new table that would show the customer ID along with all of their loans and their loan numbers

Comment: Yes, `UPDATE` query statements are typically used to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, that you are using sql server,but that would work with every rdms that support window functions

> ```
> CREATE TABLE loan
>     ([Loan Number] int, [Borrower] varchar(5), [Amount $] int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Loan
>     ([Loan Number], [Borrower], [Amount $])
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Eagle', 100),
>     (2, 'Eagle', 299),
>     (3, 'Pidge', 333),
>     (4, 'Hawk', 123)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT [Loan Number], [Borrower], [Amount $]
> , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [Borrower]) [Customer_ID] INTO Customer 
> FROM Loan
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Customer
> ```
>
> ```
> Loan Number | Borrower | Amount $ | Customer_ID
> ----------: | :------- | -------: | ----------:
>           1 | Eagle    |      100 |           1
>           2 | Eagle    |      299 |           1
>           4 | Hawk     |      123 |           2
>           3 | Pidge    |      333 |           3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dba7878bbc649de25477e01d8bddec44)*